# Помогите написать мини-программу, которая выводит треугольник

Tags: javascript, c#

Вот что должно выйти:

```
  # #
 ## ##
### ###
```

Comment: Прикрепите пример как пытались это реализовать. И определитесь все таки c# или js. Или все таки code-golf?))

Comment: Проблемы с циклами, там их будет около 4 штук

Comment: Нужен код на любом (c#,Js)

Comment: Потом переделаю если что

Comment: Да одного цикла с головой хватит, заменяете пробел перед первой решеткой на еще одну решетку и приписывайте решетку в конец

Comment: проще некуда :) `Console.WriteLine((char)32+(char)32+(char)35+(char)32+(char)35+(char)10+(char)32+(char)35+(char)35+(char)32+(char)35+(char)35+(char)10+(char)35+(char)35+(char)35+(char)32+(char)35+(char)35+(char)35);` и без *проблем*

Comment: @Alias, Идеально, у вас даже проблема с циклами решилась, и  если у АндрейNOP цикл всего один и неявный, тут их совсем нет)

Comment: [Если JS, то вот тут я отвечал на схожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365737/how-to-print-star-pattern-in-javascript-in-a-very-simple-manner/46421152#46421152), ознакомьтесь, возможно это вам поможет в дальнейшем.

Comment: @IServeladik I, попробуй все-таки доделать свои 4 цикла. На первых парах сложно, как-то с трением думается, но если посидеть спокойненько, без стресса, без спешки, то должно получиться и может даже понравиться. Или потом в другой раз попробовать если сейчас сроки сдачи дз. Можно свое решение придумать, причем не такое как здесь ответили или не такое как объясняли на уроке.

Answer (score 7):

Пожалуйста:

```
int h = 3; // Высота
var f = $"{{0,{h}}} {{0,-{h}}}";
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join("\n",
        Enumerable.Range(1, h)
            .Select(x => string.Format(f, new string('#', x)))));
```

Comment: зачем так жестоко)

Comment: будим надеяться, что под js ТС перенесёт за три минуты

Comment: Конечно спасибо, но можно как то по тупее и легче, спешли фор ми

Comment: @IServeladikI, сомневаюсь, что кто-то даст вам такое решение, которые вы сможете сдать, здесь все-таки не сервис решения домашек

Comment: не ценитель тонкостей js, но, попытался... https://pastebin.com/wkPb90BL | fix

Comment: Ааааа! Обожаю LINQ!